# What are admin hooks

Tags: plugins, hooks

I'm trying to write a new plugin and I get so confused about wp hooks to use.
What is the difference between init hook and admin_init hook, which one is fired first?

Answer (score 1):

The `init` hook is triggered a **little earlier** than the `admin_init`. *Between them is triggered `wp_loaded` and few hooks related to updating the DB.*

The `init` hook fires when WP is finished loading (**viewer-facing and administration** side).

The `admin_init` hook fires on **administration side only** (`/wp-admin/*`), therefore is triggered also by front- and back-end ajax requests (`/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php`) and POST handler (`/wp-admin/admin-post.php`).

Comment: thanks for the help @nmr, I've found a comprehensive list of action hooks available in WordPress https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference